# Power Query Convert Date (type date) to serial number

Tags: date, formatting, powerquery

I have a column in power query called "Delivery Date", type date.

I want to convert the date to serial number (the same as in excel when you change type date to "general" format. My date is "yyyy-mm-dd"

example:

"2023-02-01" formatted as "44958"

"2023-01-31" formatted as "44957"

This is the output I would like:

| Delivery Date | DateCode |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-01 | 44958 |
| 2023-01-31 | 44957 |

I've tried this code:

= Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Delivery Date", Number.From}})

as well as duplicating my "Delivery Date" column and changing Type to "Int64"

**in both cases my output is 6.38108E+17 for Feb 1st date, and 6.38107E+17 for Jan 31st date.**

I have not been able to find a solution anywhere online thus far and have been formatting it once it's loaded into excel (which is an unnecessary step).

Thanks!

Comment: There is something else going on. Either of your methods will convert a "real date" to the correct serial number. Try setting up a table with ONLY those two dates, and try your method again.

Comment: Ok, all those methods worked when I created my own simple excel table and loaded into Power Query. It must be the query I'm using that's pulling from Azure Data Explorer. Thanks for the answers and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
let  Source = #table({"Delivery Date"},{{"2023-02-01 5:00:00 AM +00:00"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Delivery Date", type datetime}}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"Delivery Date", type number}})
in  #"Changed Type1"
```

Transform to date/time

Transform again to number, without replacing original transformation

Comment: I've tried changing to decimal number, and whole number, but get the same result. n both cases my output is 6.38108E+17 for Feb 1st date, and 6.38107E+17 for Jan 31st date.

Comment: In its original source, it comes in as "2023-02-01 5:00:00 AM +00:00", which I then change to Date type, giving me "2023-02-01"